# how to read excel file in javascript without using ActiveXObject?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net

I'm just trying to upload an excel file and do some processing on it.
and want to show the progress step by step.
I've tried much to show a real progress I've used Background-worker, and Web-method etc. but no success now I'm thinking to do this With the help of JavaScript and AJAX.

Code i've tried with backgroundworker is below

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    Public Shared stopWorker As Boolean = False

    Public Function startWorker() As Int16
        If Not bw.IsBusy = True Then
            bw.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
        Return 0
    End Function

    Public Function testww(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) As Int16
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted 
        Return 0
    End Function

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        For i = 1 To 500
            If bw.CancellationPending = True Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            Else
                ' Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                bw.ReportProgress(i * 0.5)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Me.tbProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%"
    End Sub


    Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        If e.Cancelled = True Then
            Me.tbProgress.Text = "Canceled!"
        ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.tbProgress.Text = "Error: " & e.Error.Message
        Else
            Me.tbProgress.Text = "Done!"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub WorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)

        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = TryCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        If worker IsNot Nothing Then
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
            If Not stopWorker Then
                worker.RunWorkerAsync()
            Else
                While stopWorker
                    Thread.Sleep(6000)
                End While
                worker.RunWorkerAsync()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
        Dim result = startWorker()
    End Sub
End Class
```

and front-end I'm just tiring to change the values in a text box like

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Async="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbProgress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

please help me.

Comment: it is not possible to read excel file using Javascript on client pc

Comment: it is working fine but i want step by step percentage of completion of task as it shows at last when it comes out from for loop with 100%(Done!) status and user are just able to see "Done!" But i want like 1% then 2% and goes on... 100% Then Done!

Comment: you need to reload progress bar every time when anything change

Answer (score 0):

I think it is really hard to get this done with ajax. When ajax calls the site to update the progress you will get another instance of the page and also another instance of the BackgroundWorker. If you want to use Ajax you will need something "above" the page to hold the data. Maybe a session?

You should have a look at http://signalr.net/ which might help you to solve your issue:

> What can you do with ASP.NET SignalR? SignalR can be used to add any
>   sort of "real-time" web functionality to your ASP.NET application.
>   While chat is often used as an example, you can do a whole lot more.
>   Any time a user refreshes a web page to see new data, or the page
>   implements Ajax long polling to retrieve new data, is candidate for
>   using SignalR.